# Convert Date to ISO 8601 format and update value of node xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="date">11-15-2017 22:45:59</entry>
</properties>
```

I want to change the date format to ISO 8601. and update the value of date tag using xslt. 
The output xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<properties>
<entry key="date">11-15-2017T22:45:59Z</entry>
</properties>
```

I have defined a variable with the converted date value. I am using this xslt but not getting desired output.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="properties/entry[@key='date']/@value"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="entry[@key='date']">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(normalize-space($dateparam), ' ', 'T'), 'Z')"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Could someone please help me with this as I am new to XSLT.

Comment: `"properties/entry[@name='date']/@value"` => `"properties/entry[@key='date']/@value"`, and `<xsl:template match="entry[@key=date]">` => `<xsl:template match="entry[@key='date']">`, should resolve your issue.

Comment: I don't see how `<xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="properties/entry[@name='date']/@value"></xsl:variable>` does the wanted conversion, it merlely selects an input attribute node. As the notation `<xsl:text>{$dateparam}</xsl:text>` would only output the variable in XSLT `version="3.0"` and `expand-text="yes"` with an XSLT 3.0 processor, with an XSLT 2.0 processor you can use `<xsl:value-of select="$dateparam"/>`.

Comment: I am using the variable here to convert the format
<xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(normalize-space($dateparam), ' ', 'T'), 'Z')"/>

I am not getting the value of dataparam.

Comment: `entry[@key=date]` isn't going to match anything either.

Comment: @SanthoshGonuguntla - Why doesn't that xsl:value-of exist in the code in the question? Similar to AntonH's suggestion, try changing your variable to `<xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="/properties/entry[@key='date']"/>` and your match to `match="entry[@key='date']"`

Comment: After your edit you no longer have a valid 8601 date.

Comment: Added value-of, Can you pls suggest me the changes required to be made Daniel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the output you requested, you only need to change your `xsl:variable` to:

```
<xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="/properties/entry[@key='date']"/>
```

However, the requested output (`11-15-2017T22:45:59Z`) is not a valid dateTime.

This is what I would do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="/properties/entry[@key='date']"/>

  <xsl:template match="entry[@key='date']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space($dateparam),
        '^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})\s+(.*)','$3-$1-$2T$4Z')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<properties>
   <entry key="date">2017-11-15T22:45:59Z</entry>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="entry[@key='date']">
    <xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="dd" select="xs:date(substring-before(., ' '))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tt" select="xs:time(substring-after(., ' '))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dt" select="dateTime($dd, $tt)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dt,
        '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]Z')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

By the way: `<xsl:text>{$dateparam}</xsl:text>` will not work.

Use `<xsl:value-of select="$dateparam"/>` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i want to change the date 09-20-2016 20:57:27 to ISO standard. Please suggest me the changes.

Comment: updated question accordingly. 
modified the code suggested by you for this requirement.
<xsl:template match="entry[@key='DateCreated']">
    <xsl:variable name="dateparam" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="dd" select="xs:date(substring-before(., ' '))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="tt" select="xs:time(substring-after(., ' '))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="dt" select="dateTime($dd, $tt)"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($dt,
        '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01]Z')"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>